# How do I avoid an "abstract error" with a TCustomGrid descendant?

Tags: delphi

Whats the minimum I have to do to descend a new control from TCustomGrid, and get it on a form in the IDE without getting 'Abstract Error' within the IDE?

I have tried everything for days, but Im a bit of a delphi noob atm, zero percent success with TCustomGrid :(

If someone could help me out just getting a basic descendant of TCustomGrid which does nothing but implement the base TCustomGrid behavious it would be much a appreciated. Thanks.

Edit - I know how to do the basics of creating controls, I just cant do it with TCustomGrid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Abstract Error" usually means that there are virtual abstract functions you'll have to implement to make the class work. For TCustomGrid, this should be the `DrawCell` method, as you can see [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Grids.TCustomGrid_Methods).

For a complete detailed example on how to build an own grid based on TCustomGrid, see [this tutorial](http://www.podgoretsky.com/ftp/Docs/Delphi/D5/dg/custom.html#3659).

Comment: Woot! TyTyTy - its working - i was trying to overide DrawCell in published not protected. Thanks for that code example link.

Answer (score -1):

You only get abstract errors if you neglect to override and provide an implementation for a method that was declared virtual abstract in either TCustomGrid or **any** of its ancestors.

So the solution would be to find all of these (use ctrl-click on the class names to get from ancestor to ancestor) and provide an override. Start with an empty implementation of your overrides. That may cause other errors and broken/unexpected behaviour, but should get you past the abstract errors.